# *ngFor conditional where item.id === group.id

Tags: angular

I have to make some nested columns where each column has a group.id, and i need to place the items that have a matching id, how would I do this with ngFor?

so for example I have an object like this:

```
columnNames = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Opened'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Responded'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Material requested'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Material sent'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Interview requested'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Interview completed'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Follow up sent'},
    {id: 7, name: 'Follow up responded'},
    {id: 8, name: 'Article secured'},
    {id: 9, name: 'Article published'},
    {id: 10, name: 'Not interested'}
];
```

and then items that are like this:

```
{
    "contactId": 0,
    "contactName": "John Doe",
    "mediaOutletName": "Gadget",
    "pitchingInitiativeId": 0,
    "statusHistory": [
        {
            "completedDate": "2018-02-07T03:45:19.811Z",
            "storyFunnelId": 0,
            "storyFunnelStatusId": 0
        }
    ],
    "storyFunnelId": 0,
    "storyFunnelStatusId": 0,
    "updatedDate": "2018-02-07T03:45:19.811Z",
    "userId": 0
}
```

in my template need to nest in each column where `storyFunnelStatusId` = column.id

so something like this in my template:

```
<div class="board-column" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
    <div class="board-heading">
        {{ column.name }}
        <span class="count">4</span>
    </div>
    <div id="column-{{ column.id }}" class="card-body">
        <div *ngFor=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting a nested response from back end?

Comment: yes I will need to loop through individual items into the columns based off the condition above.

Comment: I have answered from what I understood. Have a look at the two for loops, columNames and colums are iterated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
<div id="column-{{ column.id }}" *ngIf="storyFunnelStatusId === column.id" class="card-body">

</div>
```

Comment: and then put my for loop for the items nested in?

Comment: which items you want to loop

Comment: so now that I think of it, I put all the items through a pipe that groups them by their `storyFunnelStatusId` so I get an object that looks like this `grouped = [0: [{item}, {item}, {item}]` and so on..

Comment: then do a ngFor for that loop

Comment: right, so i need to do an ngFor where I am only looping where the group key  equals the column.index???

Comment: yes but that has performance issue, better way is to do that on component and render

Comment: yes I was thinking of mapping the grouped to the columnNames object keys, however I need to be able to have empty columns. Hmmm. This is proving to be a pain!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164667/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-sandra-willford).